# Keybord problems

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout

recently I started experiencing problems with my keyboard. Specifically, every time I type this symbol  '';'' appears between letters or when I press the spacebar and it is quite frustrating since I have top go back and revise the whole text. I used to have two languages in my layout(Greek and English(UK)but I deleted the Greek. aNY SUGGESTIONS on how I can solve it??Th;an;k;s

Comment: B;y th;e ;way I run; U;Bb;u;ntu ;12.;04 LTS

Comment: Did you try with another keyboard?

Comment: The keybord; ;of my laptop st;arted acting the same. I could not press keys and I had the same pr;oblem so I bought a new one and it st;ar;ted act;ing th;e ;sam;e

Comment: @user216473: No doubt you are in serious trouble.. You question tells all about your problem.. :D

Comment: @SauravKumar DO YOU HAVE ANY SUGGESTIONS